# the memory could not be written error from Linux Mint in virtual box

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox

I have kali and linux mint installed with the same installation properties in virtual box. I do not get error from kali however i keep getting this error from Linux Mint 19.1.[image]

Comment: Did you check any anomaly in memory usage in `top`?

Comment: the only thing when first machine is booted, desktop does not load the task bar. I  exit full-screen mode  and it loads.

Comment: What are the installation properties of the Mint VM? You may not have allocated enough resources, especially when using a program like VSC.